# How do you change to a double skin in agario?

Tags: agar.io

I've noticed some people have a skin. When they duplicate, the second skin is different.

How do you get those?

Look at the player "Mexicano" in the picture below. His original skin was green but the duplicates are a mushroom

[image: Example of a player with two skins]

Answer (score 1):

They're called mystery skins and upgradable to upper levels where in each level a feature is added, in level 2 it shines when splitting or eating other players cells.[image]

Comment: This is not what I mean. Sometimes a player is say red color and when they split all of the other cells are black color.

It's very confusing because you think they are two different players when in reality they are the same.

Comment: @Wilmer Well, I'm saying it might be a feature of the skin? Or it might be the browser nit being able to show the animated skin (the black one you mentioned)

Comment: I was able to screenshot one such skins. Look at the picture I attached to the question.

Comment: oh I see! I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: That was a bug!

Answer (score -1):

I have no source to back up my answer, but I've been playing Agario since 2015. I have seen that happen and it was a bug which has been fixed now.

Comment: No. I just played today and I saw a guy with this double skin thing.